# AWS Aurora: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

We have a high load database in production and sometimes (about 0.0001%) we get a block of errors regarding MySQL.

We use AWS [RDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Relational_Database_Service) [Aurora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Aurora) and currently have one master and two read replicas. AWS can’t find anything on their side and tells us that it's an application or MySQL configuration issue.

This happens in totally random endpoints, so we can’t focus on a specific query or workload.

They always come in a block of three errors:

```
15:26:56 --> Severity: Warning  --> mysqli_select_db(): MySQL server has gone away
15:26:56 --> Severity: Warning  --> mysqli_select_db(): Error while reading INIT_DB's response packet. PID=1442
15:26:56 --> Unable to select database: XXXX
```

Comment: tis means that one of the timeouts hit, so you should start to increase them next you should check the queries and see if the indexes match especially on the slow queries

Comment: @nbk what timeouts should we might looking for?

Comment: see https://serverfault.com/questions/375136/what-is-the-difference-between-wait-timeout-and-interactive-timeout

Comment: interactive_timeout  and  wait_timeout =  28800

Comment: as i saud ibcrease them and see what happens ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your issue description matches the bug in Aurora 2 only fixed 2 weeks ago in 2.11.4

> Fixed an issue which can cause database connections to be closed before being established. This issue is more likely to affect database instances which open and close connections at a high rate.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraMySQLReleaseNotes/AuroraMySQL.Updates.2114.html